# I cannot perform a data "toJson" operation of a model and the list in it

Tags: flutter, fluttermap, to-json

**I cannot perform a data "toJson" operation of a model and the list in it.**

**main model**

```
class ExampleData {
  ExampleData({
    this.name,
    this.surname,
    this.otherList,
  });

  String name;
  String surname;
  List<ExampleOtherData> otherList;

  factory ExampleData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      ExampleData(
        name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["depoAdi"],
        surname: json["surname"] == null ? null : json["aciklama"],
        otherList: json["otherList"] == null
  ? null
      : List<ExampleOtherData>.from(
  json["otherList"].map((x) => ExampleOtherData.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "name": name == null ? null : name,
    "surname": surname == null ? null : surname,
    "otherList": otherList == null
        ? null
        : List<dynamic>.from(otherList.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}
```

**sub model**
list model linked to main model

```
class ExampleOtherData {
  ExampleOtherData({
    this.phone,
    this.email
  });

  String phone;
  String email;

  factory ExampleOtherData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      ExampleOtherData(
        phone: json["phone"] == null ? null : json["phone"],
        email: json["email"] == null ? null : json["email"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "phone": phone == null ? null : phone,
    "email": email == null ? null : email,
  };
}
```

**How to add main model and list model in it?**
How can I map the main model and the list model in it.

```
var newList = MainController.to.getExampleMain.map((value) => value.toJson());
await MainService.addExample(postBody: newList);
```

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: could you provide json showing in the httpresponse

Comment: Yes I know that. but I'm asking how to use it for the model and the list in it. if you examine the last code.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add toList() at the end of query.

```
var newList = MainController.to.getExampleMain.map((value) => value.toJson()).toList();
```

Comment: I tried adding it before. it gave this error. The main model is not the list, but there is the model with the list in it. Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>'

Comment: You are trying to use toJson method on otherList in your ExapmleData class right? And MainController.to.getExampleMain is your model to post to api. If it is right. You need to change your toJson method in ExapmleData class. Your toJson needs to be

Comment: "otherList": otherList == null
        ? null
        : otherList.map((x) => x.toJson()).toList(),

Comment: i tried but not working. controller.to.getMainExample.map((value) => value.toJson()); this not list. this is main data not list. I need to be able to add the data, which is a list, into it. can you just write this for me based on example data and otherListData. just this part. controller.to.getMainExample.map((value) => value.otherList.toJson().toList()); etc..

Comment: /flutter (10334): ║ Instance of '_MapStream<RefundRequestData, Map<String, dynamic>>'
I/flutter (10334): 
I/flutter (10334): ╔╣ DioError ║ DioErrorType.other
I/flutter (10334): ║  'package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart': Failed assertion: line 701 pos 16: 'data is Stream<List>': Stream type must be `Stream<List>`, but _MapStream<RefundRequestData, Map<String, dynamic>> is found.

Comment: If it is not list change it to controller.to.getMainExample.toJson() . Because you need to map otherlist not ExampleData class

Comment: and keep "otherList": otherList == null ? null : otherList.map((x) => x.toJson()).toList() this in your toJson

Comment: i think we're close. [ERROR] Error Detail - type '(dynamic) => OtherList' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'.

Comment: I have successfully sent the data. thank you so much. sağol üstad kolay gelsin.

Answer (score 1):

**Basedon on model Class**
json string

```
[{name: hi, surname: joji, otherlist: [{name: kl, surname: ja}, {name: lkl, surname: lja}]}, {name: hohi, surname: jpjoji, otherlist: [{name: kl, surname: ja}, {name: lkl, surname: lja}]}]
```

[Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=7f48b5322707744b5b078a3f57ed85a0)

**Sample Code**

```
 class MainController {
  static List<ExampleData2> to() {
    List<ExampleData2> data = [];
    List<Otherlist> otherlist = [];
    otherlist.add(new Otherlist(surname: "ja", name: "kl"));
    otherlist.add(new Otherlist(surname: "lja", name: "lkl"));
    data.add(
        new ExampleData2(name: "hi", surname: "joji", otherlist: otherlist));
    data.add(new ExampleData2(
        name: "hohi", surname: "jpjoji", otherlist: otherlist));
    return data;
  }
}
    
    
          void main() {
    
              
        //    ---------------------- json
                 var list = MainController.to().map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();
            
                print(list);
                var d = list.map((e) => ExampleData2.fromJson(e)).toList();
            
                print(d);
            }
            class ExampleData2 {
              String? name;
              String? surname;
              List<Otherlist>? otherlist;
            
              ExampleData2({this.name, this.surname, this.otherlist});
            
              ExampleData2.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
                name = json['name'];
                surname = json['surname'];
                if (json['otherlist'] != null) {
                  otherlist = <Otherlist>[];
                  json['otherlist'].forEach((v) {
                    otherlist!.add(new Otherlist.fromJson(v));
                  });
                }
              }
            
              Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
                final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
                data['name'] = this.name;
                data['surname'] = this.surname;
                if (this.otherlist != null) {
                  data['otherlist'] = this.otherlist!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
                }
                return data;
              }
            }
            
            class Otherlist {
              String? name;
              String? surname;
            
              Otherlist({this.name, this.surname});
            
              Otherlist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
                name = json['name'];
                surname = json['surname'];
              }
            
              Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
                final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
                data['name'] = this.name;
                data['surname'] = this.surname;
                return data;
              }
            }
```

Comment: I/flutter (12520): ║ Instance of 'Future<List<Otherlist>>'
I/flutter (12520): 
I/flutter (12520): ╔╣ DioError ║ DioErrorType.other
I/flutter (12520): ║  Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Future<List<Otherlist >>'

Comment: orjinal ---- var newL =
          RefundPostController.to.getReturn.map((value) => value.toJson());
      
      var newList = newL.map((e) => RefundProductListData.fromJson(e))
          .toList();

Comment: I have successfully sent the data. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate required Model automatically from JSON structure, you can use online generators e.g. [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io), just paste your JSON, select dart language and generate your model.

Comment: yes I know. There is no problem with the model. I'm sending the data from the "temporary" to the model with "toJson" on the "controller". The main model is not the list, but there is the model with the list in it.